# Is it better to brake a vehicle on an inclined or on a level section of road?

Tags: friction, everyday-life

I live near the top of a hill and every time I leave home I think of asking this question and forget by the time I might. The road is quite steep and about half way down there is a short level section. I need to slow down at some point to be at a reasonable speed to stop at the bottom of the hill.

When driving it "feels better" to brake and slow down on the level area than on an incline. Assuming I'll reach the end at the same speed in either case the final braking can be disregarded. In terms of wear on the brakes, is it better to slow down on the incline or on the level section or does it make no difference? Are there other inefficiencies I'm not considering as well? (I stay in low gear the entire time and safety is not a concern as I have the right of way and never reach an unsafe speed.)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is the maximum braking force you can apply without skidding cannot exceed the maximum possible static friction force between the tires and road, and that force is less on the incline because the normal  (perpendicular) force is less.

Comment: Good point that I hadn't thought of but (fortunately) in this case the speed doesn't come close to skidding.

Comment: It's not the speed that causes skidding, it the amount of deceleration (braking) or acceleration that causes skidding. Think about accelerating from a stopped position. If you floor the accelerator the drive wheel will spin and you go nowhere.

Comment: @BobD Thanks. Acceleration and deceleration does contribute to skidding and looking at the problem in the general way is important to consider. But speed and the car's mass, as components of momentum, affect the force of the car (or tires) acting against the force of deceleration. When braking both play a role in skidding. In narrowly thinking of my own situation I failed to consider everything (resulting in a pretty poor response).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, but whether your speed is 50 km/hr or 100 km/hr, your maximum braking deceleration without skidding is $a_{max}=\mu g$ where $\mu$ is the coefficient of static friction.  Naturally the faster you are going you are going more deceleration to stop at a safe distance, but that's not the point.  I will leave it at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What likely matters for wear is the *velocity of the vehicle at the moment of breaking* - that is, one may consider differents ecnarious, like:

1. breaking continuously while on a slope AND in the level section
2. breaking on the slope but not in the level section
3. not breaking on the slope, and then breaking on the level section

This may be made more complicated, if the slope continues after the level section. In this sense, the question is not very clearly posed (but I assume this is a part of the discussion related to the *experimentd esign*, and therefore a valid one under the community rules.)

Regarding scenario (3) it is necessary to note that on the level section the car must slow down even without the breaks applied, if one is in a low gear. This brings another uncertainty in the question: if the car is truly in a lower gear, the slope should be really steep so that it continues to accelerate... which means that one would eventually exceed the allowed/safe speed - another point that requires clarification. (I may be wrong, as my experience is mostly with a manual transmission.)

Comment: The question did say that the level section is "about half way down" which I thought clearly indicated that there was incline both before and after the level section. I understand the issu e about being in low gear and the question is about an automatic transmission. You are correct about the limited speed if using a manual transmission. (I didn't think about the distinction having switched long ago after plenty of manual driving on the hills of SF.) I'll accept your answer for examining some good points.